# Why doesn't setting the bounds of a UIView restrict its size to those bounds

Tags: swift

I would like to turn off auto layout for a while and handle the size and placement of a UIView using its `bounds`, `center`, and `transformation`.

I have a very simple 'Single View Application' example. My app has a view controller hosting the main view. In that view are two buttons, and another view (with its background set to pink) which in turn contains an image view (set to aspect fit):

[image: Xcode screenshot showing storyboard]

I've distilled my problem into a very simple UIViewController:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var imageHolderView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func loadImageButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3909/15110089915_21a12eba6a_k.jpg")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
}

@IBAction func clearConstraintsButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let bounds:CGRect = self.imageHolderView.bounds
    let center:CGPoint = self.imageHolderView.center
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.imageHolderView.constraints)
    self.imageHolderView.bounds = bounds
    self.imageHolderView.center = center
}
```

N.B. I'm trying to understand this within a more complex project, the example here is just to demonstrate the problem.

When I run the project the image has no source and so the pink UIView (`imageHolderView`) takes up much of the screen as expected:

[image: simulator screenshot before image loaded]

When I click the load image button the controller loads the image from the web into the UIImageView. Because the constraints are all still in place Auto Layout ensures that the picture is aspect-fitted in to the UIImageView constrained to its super view `imageHolderView`:

[image: simulator screenshot after image loaded]

If I now clear the constraints I expect to see no difference because the constraints set by Auto Layout are immediately replaced in code by the same values. But that's not what I see:

[image: simulator screenshot after constraints are cleared]

How do I grab the bounds and center of a UIView as set by Auto Layout, turn off Auto Layout for the UIView, and then re-establish the bounds and center from my own swift code?

Looking in the debugger the bounds on the UIView `imageHolderView` are correct, and the constraints on the UIImageView `imageView` are almost (*) still in place (which I'd hope would constrain the UIImageView to fit inside the UIView), but the bounds on the UIImageView have grown to accommodate the full sized image. Why?

(In the more complex app I then go on to resize, rotate, and translate the view with transformations. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5) states that "if the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead." The sample code does not use transformations, but as I say my real code does; I think that precludes me from setting the frame.)

(*) I say almost, because there are four constraints on the UIImageView, but in the debugger the count is two.

Comment: There's more information in a follow-on question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35687251/575530)

Comment: Did you try to set Clip Subviews option to true?

Comment: Yep - it buys me a border, but I still get the crazy resizing

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you are forgetting.

First of all, in:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.imageHolderView.constraints)
```

make sure that you are not deactivating constraints that you need. E.g. if you have a width or height constraint on `imageHolderView`, you would deactivate it using this call.

In:

```
let bounds:CGRect = self.imageHolderView.bounds
let center:CGPoint = self.imageHolderView.center
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.imageHolderView.constraints)
self.imageHolderView.bounds = bounds
self.imageHolderView.center = center
```

You are getting the `bounds` and `center` of `imageHolderView` and then you are trying to assign them back to `imageHolderView`. That's wrong because you are deactivating the constraints that set the position for `imageView`. You don't have to change the position of `self.imageHolderView` because the constraints for it are saved in its superview. On the other hand, `self.imageView` has probably all constraints deactivated, so you should be setting its position:

```
self.imageView.bounds = bounds
self.imageView.center = center
```

The `center` settings is wrong because `imageHolderView.center` is specified in the coordinate system of its superview. You should calculate the center manually from `bounds`.

```
self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(bounds.size.width / 2, bounds.size.height / 2)
```

However, the biggest problem is probably the fact, that `bounds` and `center` (or `frame`) are ignored by default in any view that is created from storyboard/xib with autolayout enabled.

You will have to manually set `imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `true`. Otherwise `frame` will be ignored by layout manager.

Comment: Is this right? [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5) states that "if the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead." The sample code does not use transformation, but I mention that my real code does. I think that precludes me from setting the frame.

Comment: @dumbledad You are right, `frame` works only if you don't use transformations, I will remove it from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

don't set the bounds, instead set the frame. try this:

```
@IBAction func clearConstraintsButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let frame = self.imageHolderView.frame
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.imageHolderView.constraints)
    self.imageHolderView. frame = frame
}
```

Comment: Is this right? [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5) states that "if the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead." The sample code does not use transformation, but I mention that my real code does. I think that precludes me from setting the frame.

Comment: I'm suspecting that when you clear the constraints, the view's origin and size are both changing. This can cause some weird behavior when then trying to change the bounds of the view since, according to apple, "changing the bounds size grows or shrinks the view relative to its center point"

Answer (score 2):

Since you are clearing contains of the view, it will remove vertical and horizontal hugging constraints of the its subviews. You can fix this by customising your holder we as,

```
class CustomHolderView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews() 
        self.imageView.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

Inside holder views layoutSubviews method you should set the frame for your image view.

Comment: I think you are on to something with layoutSubview override. I'll investigate

Answer (score 1):

`UIImageView` automatically adds constraints based on its resizing mask and its contentMode. Try to set its contentMode to `AspectFit` or `AspectFill` and manipulate its `frame` instead of its `bounds`.

Comment: It is set to AspectFit and it is set to be within its super view's (i.e. the Image Holder View's) bounds. I'm anxious about manipulating frame as the documentation says not to if you are changing the transformation

Comment: `self.imageHolderView.frame = bounds` and remove your centers manipulations.

Comment: Did not work: same problem. Did you mean `self.imageHolderView.frame = bounds` or `self.imageView.frame = bounds`? I'm hoping to leave the UIImageView subview as part of Auto Layout and just set the size and position of its super view